# :anchor not working for odt export

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I am trying to export images with odt export from org-mode and to change the anchor of the image (default to-paragraph) to "as-char".

I tried the following code:

```
 #+ATTR_ODT: :anchor "as-char"
 [[./orgmode.png]]
```

And the obtained result in LibreOffice is:

[image: Result of odt export]

The anchor of the image remains "to-paragraph". Is it a bug or a misunderstanding of the :anchor tag ?

Config: GNU Emacs 25.2.2, LibreOffice 6.0.3.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the documentation describing the `:anchor` tag is wrong, or the implementation has diverged from the documentation. This works for me in org-mode version 9.1.14 if I don't specify the quotes around the `:anchor` tag value, ie :

```
 #+ATTR_ODT: :anchor as-char
 [[./orgmode.png]]
```

It might be worth reporting this as a bug to the org-mode developers

Comment: Thanks for this answer, works very well when removing the quote (I also use org-mode version 9.1.14).